# Create Dropdown With Values From Model in Django Form

Tags: python, django, model, dropdown

I am attempting to create a dropdown field which populates with values from a model (Customers) and display it to the user.

Below is what I am attempting - not exactly sure why, but the dropdown field is not populating with any of the info from the Customer Model, it is just empty.

Views.py

```
def add_order(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CreateOrderForm(request.POST)
        objectlist = Customers.objects.all()


        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('add_manifest')#, kwargs={'reference_id': form.cleaned_data['reference']})
    #else:
    form = CreateOrderForm()
    objectlist = Customers.objects.all()
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'objectlist': objectlist,
    }

    return render(request, 'add_order.html', context)
```

Template (add_order.html)

```
<div class="container">
    <form method="POST">
      <br>
      <h2>Order Information</h2>
      <br>
 <div class="column_order">
 <select>
          {% for element in objectlist %}
            <option value="{{ element.c_name }}">
          {% endfor %}
        </select>
 </div>
</div>
```

Models.py

```
class Customers(models.Model):

    c_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    c_address = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    c_country = models.CharField(max_length=50)

def _str_(self):
    return self.c_name
```

When I go to this url and render the template, the select box displays, but there are no values in it. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You did not close the `<option>` tag and there is no option text. Try:

```
<option value="{{ element.c_name }}">{{ element.c_name }}</option>
```

It is also a good idea to set the `value` to `{{ element.pk }}` instead as there might be multiple customers with the same name since you don't enforce that column to be unique.